# Nokia Qt Mobility: Close Application On click listwidget item

Tags: qt, nokia

i am new to Nokia Qt Mobility.. and i have just started to develop an Application. My Question is:: How can i close my Application on listwidgets item click...?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried?

The obvious way is to connect the QListWidget::itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item) to some slot with a call to QApplication::exit()

Tell us if this doesn't works.

Comment: Thanks for replay... but how can i get particular item if i have more than one item in listwidget...

Comment: A pointer to the item is sent to your slot by the signal (is the one called item in your signal signature), this is a pointer to the QListWidgetItem that was clicked.

This is a basic question so please first read some basic tutorials, and then make specific questions of things that you don't get, this is better for everyone and we will be glad to help you!

For this specific topic, read the Signals and Slots info of the Qt Documentation http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/signalsandslots.html